# How deploy nuxt SSR app on Phusion Passenger

Tags: nuxt.js, passenger

I want to deploy a Nuxt.js app. My host use Phusion Passenger to wrapp it.
Phusion Passenger don't accept import/export features, vue files, ...
How can I do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok I find the solution. You must select express as the default server.